# How to get the name of the stage in an AWS Lambda function linked to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the following Lambda function configured in AWS Lambda :

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var DOC = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new DOC.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    var item = { id: 123,
                 foo: "bar"};

    var cb = function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            context.fail('unable to update hit at this time' + err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
                context.done(null, data);
        }
    };

    // This doesn't work. How do I get current stage ?
    tableName = 'my_dynamo_table_' + stage;

    dynamo.putItem({TableName:tableName, Item:item}, cb);
};
```

Everything works as expected (I insert an item in DynamoDB every time I call it).

I would like the dynamo table name to depend on the stage in which the lambda is deployed.

My table would be:

- `my_dynamo_table_staging` for stage `staging`
- `my_dynamo_table_prod` for stage `prod`

However, how do I get the name of the current stage inside the lambda ?

**Edit**: My Lambda is invoked by HTTP via an endpoint defined with API Gateway

Comment: **Update**: AWS recently rolled out a new feature called [Environment Variables and Serverless Application Model (SAM)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-environment-variables-and-serverless-application-model/). It is a built-in way to supply environment variables to your Lambda functions. ([discussion here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12999767))

Answer (score 19):

If you have checked "Lambda Proxy Integration" in your Method Integration Request on API Gateway, you should receive the `stage` from API Gateway, as well as any `stageVariable` you have configured.

Here's an example of an `event` object from a Lambda function invoked by API Gateway configured with "Lambda Proxy Integration":

```
{
"resource": "/resourceName",
"path": "/resourceName",
"httpMethod": "POST",
"headers": {
    "header1": "value1",
    "header2": "value2"
},
"queryStringParameters": null,
"pathParameters": null,
"stageVariables": null,
"requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123",
    "resourceId": "abc",
    "stage": "dev",
    "requestId": "456",
    "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
        "accountId": null,
        "cognitoIdentityId": null,
        "caller": null,
        "apiKey": null,
        "sourceIp": "1.1.1.1",
        "accessKey": null,
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
        "userArn": null,
        "userAgent": "agent",
        "user": null
    },
    "resourcePath": "/resourceName",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "apiId": "abc123"
},
"body": "body here",
"isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Comment: How do you access that within Lambda (java)

Answer (score 10):

I managed it after much fiddling. Here is a walkthrough:

*I assume that you have API Gateway and Lambda configured. If not, [here's a good guide](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/part-2). You need part-1 and part-2. You can skip the end of part-2 by clicking the newly introduced button "Enable CORS" in API Gateway*

Go to API Gateway.

Click here:

[image]

Click here:

[image]

Then expand `Body Mapping Templates`, enter `application/json` as content type, click the add button, then select mapping template, click edit

[image]

And paste the following content in "Mapping Template":

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end  
  },
  "stage" : "$context.stage"
}
```

Then click the button "Deploy API" (this is important for changes in API Gateway to take effect)

You can test by changing the Lambda function to this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var DOC = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new DOC.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var currentStage = event['stage'];

    if (true || !currentStage) { // Used for debugging
        context.fail('Cannot find currentStage.' + ' stage is:'+currentStage);
        return;
    }

// ...
}
```

Then call your endpoint. You should have a HTTP 200 response, with the following response body:

```
{"errorMessage":"Cannot find currentStage. stage is:development"}
```

---

**Important note:**
If you have a `Body Mapping Template` that is too simple, like this: `{"stage" : "$context.stage"}`, this will override the params in the request. That's why `body` and `headers` keys are  present in the `Body Mapping Template`. If they are not, your Lambda has not access to it.

Answer (score 4):

For those who use the [serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) it's already implemented and they can access to `event.stage` without any additional configurations.

See [this issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/1850) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from event variable. I logged my event object and got this.

```
{  ...
    "resource": "/test"
    "stageVariables": {
        "Alias": "beta"
    }
}
```